# Increment value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, hash-map

I have a list of dictionary let's say : `l=[{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':5,'b':6},{'a':3,'b':2}]`
and I want to have another list l2 and add 4 to the 'a' in the all dictionaries
`l2=[{'a':5,'b':2},{'a':9,'b':6},{'a':7,'b':2}]`
(the first list l shouldn't change)
so I am doing it this way but i feel there is better, it is a bit hard coded I think :

```
 l=[{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':5,'b':6},{'a':3,'b':2}]
l2=[d.copy() for d in l]
for v in l2:
    v['a']=v['a']+4
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Currently this seems somewhat hypothetical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should have spaces around `=`, and `+=` would shorten it a bit. And I'd be consistent with the variable name (not switch from `d` to `v`) and use better names for the lists (`l` looks too much like `1` and is just too short for something presumably living longer (unlike `d`, which I find ok in such small contexts)):

```
lst2 = [d.copy() for d in lst]
for d in lst2:
    d['a'] += 4
```

I'd say that's alright then. But here are two alternatives:

```
>>> [d | {'a': d['a'] + 4} for d in lst]
[{'a': 5, 'b': 2}, {'a': 9, 'b': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 2}]
```

```
>>> [{**d, 'a': d['a'] + 4} for d in lst]
[{'a': 5, 'b': 2}, {'a': 9, 'b': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: thank you , this is what I was looking for ,i was feeling it can be done in one line of code, and yes for the variables I know it was just a quick example  of what I wanted to do in my real code I  am using more significant variable names